# How do I setup ocamlinit so that ppx works?

Tags: ocaml, utop, ppx

This is my ocamlinit:

```
(* Added by OPAM. *)
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;

(* ## added by OPAM user-setup for ocamltop / base ## 3ec62baf6f9c219ae06d9814069da862 ## you can edit, but keep this line *)

#use "topfind";;
(* ## end of OPAM user-setup addition for ocamltop / base ## keep this line *)

#thread;;

(* #ppx "ppx-jane -as-ppx";; *)
#require "ppx_jane";;
#require "core.top";;
#require "async";;
#require "core_extended";;


open Core.Std;;
```

With this exactly, I get this in utop

```
utop # type test = char list [@@deriving show];;
Error: Cannot locate deriver show
```

If I use the line beginning with `#ppx` instead of `#require "ppx_jane"`, I get this error

```
utop # type test = char list [@@deriving show];;
Error: ppx_type_conv: 'show' is not a supported type type-conv generator
```

How should I set up ocamlinit to use `[@@deriving show]`?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to have it working using `#require "ppx_deriving.show";;` (with or without `#require "ppx_jane";;`).

Comment: I tried that, but I got `No such package: deriving.show`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pierre's suggestion, I found that I *needed* the line with `ppx_jane`.

Also, I used `#require "ppx_deriving.std"` instead of just `ppx_deriving.show` to get `ord` and the rest of the stuff too.

Here's my full ocamlinit

```
(* Added by OPAM. *)
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;

(* ## added by OPAM user-setup for ocamltop / base ## 3ec62baf6f9c219ae06d9814069da862 ## you can edit, but keep this line *)
#use "topfind";;
(* ## end of OPAM user-setup addition for ocamltop / base ## keep this line *)

#thread;;

#require "ppx_jane";;
#require "core.top";;
#require "async";;
#require "core_extended";;

#require "ppx_deriving.std";;

open Core.Std;;
```

Comment: Alas! It still does not work in the emacs utop. When I do C-c C-b, utop seems to treat [@@deriving show] as if it weren't there.

Comment: However, if I do C-x C-e individually on each command, utop seems to be ok with everything.

Comment: yep, https://github.com/ocaml-community/utop/issues/331